# VB.net Return value of method. System.__Com.object

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, com, upnp

I know it's a stupid question but I cannot find info about it.

```
Public Function TestFunc() As String

        Dim lMapper = cRouter.StaticPortMappingCollection
        Dim lMappedPort As NATUPNPLib.IStaticPortMapping
        Dim Test As String

        Test = lMapper.Add(80, "UDP", 8080, "192.168.1.100", True, "Local Web Server").ToString
        MsgBox(Test)
End Function
```

lMapper.Add will return something like here S_OK and etc -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366148(v=vs.85).aspx

How to get this value? By my way I get *System.__ComObject* ;[

Thank you very much for an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to cast it to an IStaticPortMapping like this

```
 lMappedPort  = DirectCast(lMapper.Add(80, "UDP", 8080, "192.168.1.100", True, "Local Web Server"), IStaticPortMapping)
```

Comment: Hm.. And how should I check an answer of lMapper.Add?

Comment: that depends what exactly are you looking for ?

Comment: _Return value
If the method succeeds the return value is S_OK.
If the method fails, the return value is one of the following error codes._

This.